# printf using in /bin/bash

Tags: linux, bash, macos, printf

I use printf in /bin/bash (OS X standard GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

```
#!/bin/bash
latest_version=\
$((curl -s http://java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp 2>/dev/null || wget -q -O - http://java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp) | grep 'latest8' |sed -E "s/.*= //" |tr -d "';")
echo $latest_version
printf "%s \n" $latest_version
```

I want to get a string "1.8.0_102" (as of 2016/7/24)

This shows

```
#echo
1.8.0_101
#printf
8.0_101
```

I want to make the string in red and the script will be run in both OS X and linux, so I do not want to use echo.

Why can't I get 1.8.0_101 by printf?

Further more what is wrong with this below?

```
printf "Get the latest Java \033[1;31m %s \033[m from Oracle.\n" $latest_version
```

It also does not work...

I have a hint... when I put

```
latest_version=1.8.0_101
```

then it works.

so the variable input to latest_version by $() is working wrong?

Comment: In the meanwhile I found a shorter solution: 
`latest_version=$((curl -s http://java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp 2>/dev/null || wget -q -O - http://java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp) | grep latest8 | cut -f 2 -d\')`

Comment: The `grep`, `sed`, `tr` pipe should be a single `sed` command: `sed -n "/latest8/{s/.*= //;s/[';\r]//g;p}"`

Comment: Or `sed -n "/latest8/s/.*'\([^']*\)'.*/\1/p"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute:

```
printf "%q \n" $latest_version
```

you get:

```
$'1.8.0_101\r'
```

and you can see the redundant `\r` (carriage returns) character.

To fix this add the `\r` to your `tr` command and that will work like a charm:

```
latest_version=$((curl -s http://java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp 2>/dev/null || wget -q -O - http://java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp) | grep 'latest8' |sed -E "s/.*= //" |tr -d "';\r")
printf "%s \n" $latest_version
```

outputs:

```
1.8.0_101
```

Comment: @hek2mgl I prefer to answer the OP question with the least modifications to his code so he can understand easily what went wrong

Comment: I understand the problem now. Thank you. But how can you see if we have \r in the latest_version in my expression.

Comment: As I wrote, use `printf "%q \n" $latest_version`

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe your `curl` with `awk` to parse latest version:

```
latest_version=$(curl -s http://java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp |
awk -F= '/latest8/{gsub(/^[^[:digit:]]*|\x27.*$/, "", $2); print $2}')
```